# Does the level of your First Stringers matter?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

You can have 5 first stringers in your squad, but can only bring one with you as a sub. If you really only ever take the same sub with you (I like my healer...) should I really worry/try to level up the other first stringers? Does it increase their effectiveness in other aspects of the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The level also helps you get more rewards in the mini games like meowster hunt and the fishing stuff. They will also level from doing such mini games.

Personally, I like to rotate what I bring on my quest because reserve palico means they will have more enthusiasm, and higher enthusiasm means they will use skills more often (I think the level also plays a part on how often they use skills?).

You won't really be missing out much stuff if you only focus on one palico, but since there's a level cap for palicos, it doesn't hurt to level all your palicos.